# EXTJS: nodes deselected in multi-select tree panel on right click (itemcontextmenu)

Tags: extjs, tree

I have a tree panel which has multiselect enabled (selModel:{MODE:MULTI}). If multiple nodes are selected then you right click to activate context menu, all selected nodes except for node that was right clicked on get deselected.

The outcome im looking for is the nodes stay selected, so I can click a menu item and get IDs of all selected Nodes.

There was a bug created for this issue couple years ago and Sencha introduced a new config, ignoreRightMouseSelection, which if set to true, doesnt treat a right click as a selection. But this config is for RowModel. I am using a tree Panel.

The event I'm listening for is treepanels "itemcontextmenu", to show contextmenu

any help appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by adding one more parameter to selModel.

```
selModel: (
{
    mode: 'MULTI', ignoreRightMouseSelection:true
})
```

Try it.